# Wireless No Longer Works on MacBook

Tags: wireless-networking, macbook, boot-camp

I have a weird problem.

I have a MacBook with Snow Leopard installed. I installed Windows 7 Ultimate in another partition via Boot Camp. Before this afternoon, my wireless internet worked in the Windows partition (which is my default). I installed the Boot Camp update that was requested when updating iTunes. Since this update, I have not been able to use the wireless connection in my Windows 7 partition.

I can successfully access the internet wirelessly in the Mac OS partition. I can also successfully access the internet from my wife's Windows 7 laptop. To further narrow the problem, I have confirmed that I can access the internet through the Windows 7 partition on my MacBook using a cat-5 cable plugged directly into my router. This problem is specific to when I attempt to access the internet wirelessly.

I have no idea how to fix this. I am not a network/server type person. Can someone please provide me some help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If Bootcamp was updated, most likely you will need to redownload and install the [Windows Components](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#macoscomponents) that will install the wireless driver.